# Android HorizontalScrollView scroll by page

Tags: android, android-widget, slideshow

I have implemented a slideshow in my Android app using . This works well except that I want to scroll to next image on a scroll gesture (now it just scrolls past few images before decelerating). I have couldn't find a appropriate way to do this, should I be using a FrameLayout instead ? How do I scroll to the next (or previous) image on scroll gesture ?

Answer (score 2):

From your description it sounds like right now you have your slideshow implemented as a series of images in a scrollview, is that correct?

Rather than placing it in a scrollview and allowing that view to do the scrolling, you could display a single image and listen for a fling or scroll gesture on the image (see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)).  When you detect the gesture you could then manually change the image.

If you want it to animate the image coming onto the screen, you could use an [animation](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html).

Comment: gesture documentation link is incorrect (http://www.govavi.com/locations.php?location_id=111&utm_source=league_welcome) Do you still have the correct link?

Comment: @ohhorob Heh, woops, sorry about that.  I'm not sure what the link was supposed to be pointing to, but probably just the android docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up using

```
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (velocityX <= 0 ){
        // hack - send event to simulate right key press
        KeyEvent rightKey  = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT);
        this.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT, rightKey);

        rightKey = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT);
        this.onKeyUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT, rightKey);            

    }else{
        // hack - send event to simulate left key press
        KeyEvent leftKey = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT);
        this.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT, leftKey);

        leftKey = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT);
        this.onKeyUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT, leftKey);
    }


    // your callback activity if you have one:
    if( callbackActivity != null ){
        callbackActivity.didFlingGallery();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: you should probably select a valid answer for your question, if you think it was answered properly

Answer (score 0):

the moment you post a question you realize the answer! I went from using Gallery to HorizontalScrollView back to using Gallery. Just shows my n00bness. Gallery solved my problem nicely. I have a custom class that extends Gallery and overrides onFling(...). In this reset the velocityX to say -300 or 300 depending on the direction, this results in scrolling to the next "page".